# How to generate popup after some time of user come into site in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, global-asax

i need to generate popup window on webpage in asp.net after 2 minutes or after browsing two web pages in website of user come into website based on some database conditions,and that popup should appear irrespective of page refreshing, page_load i.e even user refreshes page its doesn't matter popup should come after that exact time, and once  popup came it shouldn't appear in same session. for this weather i need generate new session in global.asax for counting time or counting no.of pages browsed  or how to implement this ??

Comment: User setTimeout and open popup. use bootstrap modal

Comment: thnx for reply, setTimeout() will again execute if page gets reloads and again pop up will come right ?? it shouldn't  happen.

Comment: @saaduu: you will have to use a javascript accessible cookie which stores the flag of popup status and a countdown value.

Comment: @saaduu, once popup, user clicking second and third page. do you want this popup to be opened in second and third page after 2 minutes

Comment: @Venkatraman "No" once pop came it should not appear in any page in site

Comment: Ok. its once for the whole site. when it should come back again. if they clear cache again then they can see that again ?

Comment: @saaduu, check my answer which is browser specific. hope you are fine with that !

Comment: @saaduu What have you tried ?

Comment: @Shrivallabh, when user opens for first time, it will trigger the function and open popup and set localstorage flag. when this function triggered in other pages for once. it will fail with localstorage condition !

Comment: @saaduu, are you still stuck with issue ?

Comment: @Venkatraman , as i asked in my question **after browsing two web pages in website** we could able manage that but trying to do Time based also

Comment: Below code applies to time base as well !

Comment: @saaduu, let me know your current issue

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of conditions, lets talk about showing popup after 2 mins.

To do this, use `setInterval Event` of javascript.

```
var timerID = setInterval(function() {
// your code goes here...
}, 60 * 1000 * 2);
```

Now, this will be executed after every 2 mins Elapsed. If you want to do this just once, un-register the Event by below code.

```
clearInterval(timerID);
```

You may also use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), jQuery's delay() function and lot more.

See Example attached in this [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) for delay().
Below is the main part of code from example.

```
$( "div.first" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

See [this Example from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout) for setTimeout

Below is the main part of code for setTimeout

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
});
```

Now, you can pair these js logics with the code behind logics to get all the desired conditions.

Comment: delay is not a replacement for `setTimeout`. delay should be used only for jquery based effects. this info can be found on jquery documentation which you have referred in ur ans

Comment: @CerlinBoss

Can you please eleborate and tell me when to use delay(), setTimeout() and setInterval()?

I am not sure when to use what.

Comment: settimeout is for **one time** delayed task, setinterval is for **continuous** delayed tasks and delay if for animation queuing

Comment: You would never use setInterval for a one off thing. Also please link to better documentation such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage` for condition and `setTimeout` to run once but its browser specific.

```
setTimeout( function() {
 if(!localStorage.getItem('isPopupRendered') ) {
  // open your modal.
  console.log('open Modal');
  localStorage.setItem('isPopupRendered', true);
 }
}, 60 * 1000 * 2 );
```